# Type of dataclass instance is not recognized after pickling

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pickle, python-dataclasses

I am using custom objects (ie. instances of a dataclass) as the Index of a pandas dataframe.

Sometimes when I pickle the dataframe (or an object with the dataframe as an attribute) I get strange behaviour where Python gets confused as to the type of the objects.

e.g.

```
x = s.flags.iloc[0].df.index[0] # This is not important, it's just loading the 
                                # file from pickle.
y = Quarter(2021, 3) # This is the relevant dataclass

for test in (type, hash, int, str):
    print(f'{test.__name__}: {test(x)}, {test(y)}')
```

The output is:

```
type: <class '__main__.Quarter'>, <class '__main__.Quarter'>
hash: 8087, 8087
int: 8087, 8087
str: 2021 Q3, 2021 Q3
```

but:

```
type(x) == type(y)
>>> False

type(x) == Quarter
>>> False
```

Not even sure what to look into to see why the comparison is failing.

Comment: what you get if you print type(y) and type(x)

Comment: From [What can be pickled and unpickled?](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled): "Similarly, classes are pickled by named reference, so the same restrictions in the unpickling environment apply." and "Similarly, when class instances are pickled, their class’s code and data are not pickled along with them. Only the instance data are pickled. " It sounds like  `pickle` is creating a *new* class with much of the same metadata as `Quarter`, but they are still distinct classes.

Comment: Try `print(id(type(x)), id(type(y)))` and you'll see they are not the same class.

Comment: Another passage from the `pickle` documentation: "`marshal` cannot be used to serialize user-defined classes and their instances. `pickle` can save and restore class instances transparently, however the class definition must be importable and **live in the same module** as when the object was stored." The emphasized part may be most relevant to the problem you are having.

Comment: @chepner. Since it says "__main__.Quarter" for both objects, the classes seem to live in the same module, the main module.

Comment: That's the name that was set when the class was *first* defined. It doesn't mean the reconstituted class is defined in `__main__`.